# query with case column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

In a query, I have a column like this:

```
case when X = 1 then
  case when Y <> 0 then YY else XX end
    else ZZ
end as MyColumn
```

Is there a way, in another column, to check the above column value referencing `MyColumn` instead of rewriting the case statement?

I should value another column based on the `MyColumn` value.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "check the above column value". Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

No, not without either:

- duplicating the logic in subsequent columns
- doing the initial CASE evaluation in a derived table/inline view:

  ```
  SELECT aa.mycolumn,
         CASE 
           WHEN aa.mycolumn = ? THEN ....
         END AS next_mycolumn_evaluation
    FROM (SELECT CASE
                   WHEN X = 1 THEN
                    CASE WHEN Y <> 0 THEN YY 
                      ELSE XX END
                   ELSE ZZ 
                 END AS mycolumn
            FROM ...) aa
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately my query is a View, so I think I have to duplicate the logic. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @opeara: SQL Server allows derived tables/inline views in views

Comment: Ah, cool, I would try, but sorry, I don't understand cleary your code. I'll google Inline Views by the way, many thanks.

Comment: I got it thanks! About performances, there are particular differences between the 2 ways to do this?

Comment: @opeara: Derived tables/inline views are commonly referred to as subqueries, but I disagree with that terminology.

Comment: @opeara: Performance wise, a single pass is better than using a derived table/inline view, assuming it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, (and I may not), (ssuming X, Y, XX, YY, and ZZ are other columns in this table),  you could create a calculated column on this table, that ues this expression as it's formula ..

```
Alter Table TableName Add NewColumn 
   as Case when X = 1 then
       Case when Y <> 0 YY else XX end
       else ZZ end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it with subqueries. For example:

```
Select someTable.ID, someTable.A, someTable.B,
    case subT.myColumn = 0 then 'BLARG' else 'huh?' end As outerMyColumn
from someTable,
    (Select ID, case when X = 1 then
      case when Y <> 0 YY else XX end
        else ZZ
    end as MyColumn
    From someTable
    where someCondition) subT
where subT.ID = someTable.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Write like that 
case when X = 1 and Y <> 0 then YY
     When X = 1 and Y = 0 then XX
    else ZZ end
end as MyColumn

there is only one case in this.